# Spark Structured Streaming error Error reading field 'topic_metadata'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to run a very simple example.  I have a Kafka `readStream` that reads from a Kafka topic.  I am running spark 2.4.0 and Kafka 0.10.2

```scala
var streamingInputDF =
  spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "twitter-topic")
    .load()
```

A console `writeStream`:

```scala
val activityQuery = streamingInputDF.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .outputMode("append")
  .start()

activityQuery.awaitTermination()
```

However when I start the console `writeStream` I get the following exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Query [id = d21cd9b4-7f51-4f5f-acbf-943dfaaeb7e5, runId = c2b2c58d-7afe-4ca5-bc36-6a3f496c19b3] terminated with exception: Error reading field 'topic_metadata': Error reading array of size 881783, only 41 bytes available
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:295)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'topic_metadata': Error reading array of size 881783, only 41 bytes available
  at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Schema.read(Schema.java:73)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.parseResponse(NetworkClient.java:380)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleCompletedReceives(NetworkClient.java:449)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:269)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
```

Comment: Which Kafka library are you using?

Comment: This error usually occurs when there is some version mismatch. Please verify that all the libraries you are using are of the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added kafka-clients-0.10.2.2.jar to the spark-submit command line and this error went away

Comment: Spark 2.4 added Kafka 2.0 clients, by the way